# Diagnose/Debug potential stack corruption .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windbg, memory-corruption

I think I have a curly one here... I have an WinForms application that crashes fairly regularly every hour or so when running as an x64 process. I suspect this is due to stack corruption and would like to know if anyone has seen a similar issue or has some advice for diagnosing and detecting the issue.

The program in question has no visible UI. It's just a message window that sits in the background and acts as a sort of 'middleware' between our other client programs and a server.

It dies in different ways on different machines. Sometimes it's an 'APPCRASH' dialog that reports a fault in ntdll.dll. Sometimes it's an 'APPCRASH' that reports our own dll as the culprit. Sometimes it's just a silent death. Sometimes our unhandled exception hook logs the error, sometimes it doesn't.

In the cases where Windows Error Reporting kicks in, I've examined memory dumps from several different crash scenarios and found the same Managed exception in memory each time. This is the same exception I see reported as an unhandled exception in the cases where we it logs before it dies.

I've also been lucky (?) enough to have the application crash while I was actively debugging with Visual Studio - and saw that same exception take down the program.

Now here's the kicker. This particular exception was thrown, caught and swallowed in the first few seconds of the program's life. I have verified this with additional trace logging and I have taken memory dumps of the application a couple of minutes after application startup and verified that exception is still sitting there in the heap somewhere. I've also run a memory profiler over the application and used that to verify that no other .NET object had a reference to it.

The code in question looks a bit like this (vastly simplified, but maintains the key points of flow control)

```
public class AClass
{
    public object FindAThing(string key)
    {
        object retVal = null;
        Collection<Place> places= GetPlaces();

        foreach (Place place in places)
        {
            try
            {
                retval = place.FindThing(key);
                break;
            }
            catch {} // Guaranteed to only be a 'NotFound' exception
        }

        return retval;
    }
}

public class Place
{
    public object FindThing(string key)
    {
        bool found = InternalContains(key); // <snip> some complex if/else logic

        if (code == success)
            return InternalFetch(key);

        throw new NotFoundException(/*UsefulInfo*/);
    }
}
```

The stack trace I see, both in the event log and when looking at the heap with windbg looks a bit like this.

```
Company.NotFoundException:
    Place.FindThing()
    AClass.FindAThing()
```

Now... to me that reeks of something like stack corruption. The exception is thrown and caught while the application is starting up. But the pointer to it survives on the stack for an hour or more, like a bullet in the brain, and then suddenly breaches a crucial artery, and the application dies in a puddle.

Extra clues:

- The code within 'InternalFetch' uses some Marshal.[Alloc/Free]CoTask and pinvoke code. I have run FxCop over it looking for portability issues, and found nothing.
- This particular manifestation of the issue is only affecting x64 code built in release mode (with code optimization on). The code I listed for the 'Place.Find' method reflects the optimized .NET code. The unoptimized code returns the found object as the last statement, not 'throw exception'.
- We make some COM calls during startup before the above code is run... and in a scenario where the above problem is going to manifest, the very first COM call fails. (Exception is caught and swallowed). I have commented out that particular COM call, and it does not stop the exception sticking around on the heap.
- The problem *might* also affect 32 bit systems, but if it does - then the problem does not manifest in the same spot. I was only sent (typical users!) a few pixels worth of a screen shot of an 'APP CRASH' dialog, but the one thing I could make out was 'StackHash_2264' in the faulting module field.

EDIT:

**Breakthrough!**

I have narrowed down the problem to a particular call to `SetTimer`.
The pInvoke looks like this:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern IntPtr SetTimer(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr nIDEvent, int uElapse, TimerProc CB);

internal delegate void TimerProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint nMsg, IntPtr nIDEvent, int dwTime);
```

There is a particular class that starts a timer in its constructor. Any timers set before that object is constructed work. Any timers set after that object is constructed work. Any timer set *during* that constructor causes the application to crash, more often than not. (I have a laptop that crashes maybe 95% of the time, but my desktop only crashes 10% of the time).

Whether the interval is set to 1 hour, or 1 second, seems to make no different. The application dies when the timer is due - usually by throwing some previously handled exception as described above. The callback does not actually get executed. If I set the same timer on the very next line of managed code after the constructor returns - all is fine and happy.

I have had a debugger attached when the bad timer was about to fire, and it caused an access violation in 'DispatchMessage'. The timer callback was never called. I have enabled the MDAs that relate to managed callbacks being garbage collected, and it isn't triggering. I have examined the objects with sos and verified that the callback still existed in memory, and that the address it pointed to was the correct callback function.

If I run '!analyze -v' at this point, it usually (but not always) reports something along the lines of 'ERROR_SXS_CORRUPT_ACTIVATION_STACK'

Replacing the call to SetTimer with Microsoft's 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' class also stops the crash. I've used a Reflector on the class and can see internally it still calls SetTimer - but does not register a procedure. Instead it has a native window that receives the callback. It's pInvoke definition actually looks wrong... it uses 'ints' for the eventId, where MSDN documentation says it should be a UIntPtr.

Our own code *originally* also used 'int' for nIDEvent rather than IntPtr - I changed it during the course of this investigation - but the crash continued both before and after this declaration change. So the only real difference that I can see is that we are registering a callback, and the Windows class is not.

So... at this stage I can 'fix' the problem by shuffing one particular call to SetTimer to a slightly different spot. But I am still no closer to actually understanding what is so special about starting the timer within that constructor that causes this error. And I dearly would like to understand the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Can you make the problem go away by removing the parts of the code? If you can, which parts, `InternalFetch` for instance? Can you narrow it down to a single spot/call?

Comment: So far I haven't been able to narrow it down by removing code. But  the thing is, I don't really want to, if I can help it. Due to the nature of the issue, if I make it 'go away', I won't know for certain whether I've solved the problem or now some other part of the program's memory is corrupted.

What I'm hoping for is to be able to use, say, some clever WinDbg-ing to poinpoint where the app is going off the rails, and work out the cause of the corruption before moving too code around.

Comment: Sorry - not sure I understand what you mean? Race condition where? The problematic exception is being thrown/caught on the main thread (WinForms UI thread). The only other threads in existence are just sitting and waiting on a WaitHandle at this stage. And the problem is not intermittent, in that this exception always ends up hanging around in memory... even if the program doesn't actually choke on it for a while.

Comment: .NET Doesn't get stack corruption. Also, which version of .NET?

Comment: You'd think... But I have 100% verified the exception that ultimately crashes the application is thrown and apparently caught an hour or more earlier. Would love to hear any other theories or explanations.

Comment: I suspect the Exception in memory is a red herring.  If your memory profiling shows that the Exception instance is not rooted, the GC probably just hasn't gotten around to cleaning it up.  From the looks of things, this Exception is expected to be thrown by your normal application logic, so it's not necessarily surprising that you'll have an instance of it in the heap.  The corruption is almost certainly happening in the unmanaged code.

Answer (score 3):

Just briefly thinking about it it sounds like an x64 interop issue (i.e., calling x32 native functions from x64 managed code is fraught with danger). Does the problem go away if you force your application to compile as x32 platform from within project properties?

You can read suggestions on forcing x32 compile during x32/x64 development on Dotnetrocks. Richard Campbell's suggestion is that Visual Studio should default to x32 platform and not AnyCPU.
http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=341 ([transcript](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dnr/dotnetrocks_0341_brian_peek.pdf)).

With regard to advanced debugging, I have not had a chance to debug x64 interop code, but i hear that this book is an great resource: [Advanced .NET Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002YYWEKE).

Finally, one thing you might try is [force Visual Studio to break when an exception is thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: That was my first thought too - so I did a very thorough review of all our Interop code, even code I sure wasn't being called prior to that point, and I'm feeling confident it should all be correct. As for whether it happens when running as x86, I'm afraid the answer is _maybe_. Certainly the issue where an exception hangs around long after it should have been eaten by the GC and eventually kills the program goes away. But I have a tantalizing hint in bug report about a 'random crash' that it might happen in a different fashion on x86

Comment: Kewl. I'm glad it's getting better though. Unless you need x64 for more memory, I really would compile as x32 and chase down whatever issue you have there. I remember reading that as a best practice in a few places and hear it quite a bit on dotnetrocks.com.

Comment: Thanks for the leads... will continue to investigate. Unfortunately I don't have any memory dumps or leads that would let me confirm if the problem is even occurring on an x86 build - but I'll keep on plugging away, debugging the assembly, and see if I spot something.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [DebugDiag for x64](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) or Windbg to write a dump on `Kernel32!TerminateProcess` and second chance exception on .NET which should give you the actual `.excr`  context frame of the exception that occurred.

This should help you in identifying the call-stack for the process terminate.

IMO it could be mostly because of PInvoke calls. You could use [Managed Debugging Assistants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163606.aspx) to debug these issues.

If MDA is used along with Windbg it would give out  messages that would be helpful in debugging

[image]

Also I have found tools from the http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/ team are extremely handy when dealing with interop

**EDIT**

This should give an answer why it is not working in 64 bit [Issue with callback method in SetTimer Windows API called from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678788/issue-with-callback-method-in-settimer-windows-api-called-from-c-code) .

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers. Sadly the stack inbalance MDA does not work on x64 processes and the cltinterop codeplex tool only works with .NET 4.0 (and this is a 3.5 application). The pInvokeLog MDA did help me find and verify the signatures of all our own pInvoke methods.  I feel like I am making progress! If only in the vast number of things I am ruling out. The process is still dying on the hour, but now on a completely different exception that I know is thrown and consumed entirely within the .NET J# core library

Comment: Wasn't the exception/ call-stack (.NEt J#) from the process terminate helpful in identifying the cause ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The application mostly dies when the framework is  calling 'DispatchMessage' or some method thereabouts, i.e. not in 'our code' at all, and just doing basic message pump processing. After modifying our code to remove the 'try/catch/swallow' in my sample code, the application still died on the hour with a completely different exception that had earlier been caught/swallowed.

Comment: Something very interesting... the stack trace varies somewhat each time. It's always somewhere within USER32!DispatchMessageWorker. Usually it's somewhere within UserCallWinProc trying to dereference a null pointer. At this time I can alwats see the values '113' and '246' in the registers. '0x113' would be WM_TIMER... don't know what 246 is. However, several times now I've seen it die trying to execute the instruction at address '246'. (Which it obviously cannot do).

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like a corruption issue.  I would go through all of your interop calls and ensure that all of the parameters to the DllImport'ed functions are the correct types.  For exmaple, using an int in place of an IntPtr will work in 32 bit code but can crash 64 bit.

I would use a site like [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) to verify all of the signatures.